# PHP Copy Function Path Mistake

Tags: php, path, copy

I am on a linux server and want to do following

First Create a Directory in abc/data with name "123" so it become

abc/data/123

and then copy file edf/igk/123/aa.jpg to abc/data/123/aa.jpg

but don't know where is problem

My Code

```
mkdir('abc/data/123');
copy("edf/igk/123/aa.jpg","abc/data/123/aa.jpg ");
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Does mkdir execute successfully?

Comment: Do you have permissions to create the folder in your current path? Try ini_set('display_errors',true); and error_reporting(E_ALL) and see if you get any error messages.

Comment: You're using relative paths... are you sure the code is executing in the proper place?  Does abc/data exist first?  What is the output?

Comment: is the space character on the end of your file name intentional... because "aa.jpg " may not exist while "aa.jpg" does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mkdir() will only create a single directory (the one at the END of the path specification), unless you turn on its second flag:

```
mkdir('abc/data/123', 0777, TRUE);
                            ^^^^
```

Without that flag, the 'abc' and 'abc/data' directories MUST exist before you can create the '123' directory. With the flag enabled, PHP will create any missing intermediate directories for you.

As well, since you're using relative paths, the 'edf' directory must exist as a subdirectory in whatever directory is your "current working directory". If it's not in your cwd, then you'll have to change you path to point to it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the space behind "jpg":

```
"abc/data/123/aa.jpg "
```